# initDate Issue in angular ui bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have datepicker ,in which i want to configure **initDate** so that if model value is null then datepicker show default selected date.
Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="input_empdob"  ng-readonly="isEmployeeRelieved" readonly placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" min="mindobDate" max="maxdobDate" ng-change="setYearOfPassing(); setJoiningDate();" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="employee.dob" datepicker-options="dateOptions" is-open="emp_dob_opened" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" name="input_empdob"/>
             <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event); emp_dob_opened = true;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
             </span>
```

and in controller i have configured **datepicker-options** like:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
            'init-date': new Date(1991,01,02)
        };
```

at first time while loading it behaves fine, but when on save, when i clear model value then it does not show initDate properly as configured.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you mean by after clearing model, it does not show initDate?

Comment: There is an outstanding issue with a pull request pending here [`issue2331`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2331)

Comment: @pankajparkar when i clear `employee.dob` it should show 1991-01-02 as default selected date,but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use it too, didn't work.

so, i am using the initialization with the model.

in my controller i set it like:

```
$scope.initialDate: $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```